# Kafka Warning: sasl.jaas.config should be prefixed with SASL mechanism name

Tags: apache-kafka

Although my Kafka cluster works fine, all nodes print the folllowing warning:

```
WARN Server config sasl.jaas.config should be prefixed with SASL mechanism name,
ignoring config (org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasContext)
```

This is my `server.properties` file:

```
broker.id=0
zookeeper.connect=zk1.intra:2181,zk2.intra:2181,zk3.intra:2181
authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer
listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://:9092
security.inter.broker.protocol= SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="admin" password="admin";
super.users=User:admin
```

I'm using Kafka 2.5.1.

With the exact same confiuration on 2.5.0, there is no such warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation for [sasl.jaas.config](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#sasl.jaas.config):

> For brokers, the config must be prefixed with listener prefix and SASL mechanism name in lower-case. For example,
>
> `listener.name.sasl_ssl.scram-sha-256.sasl.jaas.config=com.example.ScramLoginModule required;`

In the example from the documentation, the `sasl.jaas.config` part is prefixed by the SASL mechanism name `listener.name.sasl_ssl.scram-sha-256.`

Given the rest of your configuration, you want to use the prefix `listener.name.sasl_plaintext.plain.`. That is:

`listener.name.sasl_plaintext.plain.sasl.jaas.config=    org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="admin" password="admin" user_admin="admin";`

Comment: Tried your suggestion but this time brokers don't start and spill this error: `KafkaServer id=0] Connection to node 1 (kafka2.intra/10.12.68.12:9092) failed authentication due to: Authentication failed: Invalid username or password (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)`

Comment: @RamazanPolat I would guess that your JAAS config also needs to configure the password for the admin user. I think it's something like this:

`listener.name.sasl_plaintext.plain.sasl.jaas.config=    org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="admin" password="admin" user_admin="admin";`